# Showing unconstant number of columns in Reporting Services

Tags: sql, service, reporting-services, reporting

i have a query which returns unconstant number of columns.
How can i use this in reporting services?

```
SET @aaa =  ( 'select '+  @str+ ' from personel.fnt_hede(1,21,0) ')

EXECUTE (@aaa )
```

somehow i generate @str and use in this way.

I hope , i expressed myself clearly :) 
thanks in advance..

Comment: Why are you using a dynamic query in this case?

Comment: I have a page for users to choose what they want to see in report. They may want to see name and phone number or name,surname, email.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - SSRS needs a clearly defined resultset to be able to design reports.

Instead of using a custom query, use a query with all the available fields included, and then pass parameter values to the report to indicate which ones should be displyed.

Answer (score 1):

One option, is to return a fixed set of columns (assuming there is a definable set) and then show/hide the appropriate columns in the report.

Or, you could use a [Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334.aspx) in your report. You would have to return data in a different approach though, basically as a list of key/value data values that the Matrix can pivot. [Here's a post](http://sonalimendis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/dynamic-column-rdls.html) that came in handy when I was looking into this scenario. This approach turned out to work well in a situation where I too do not know up front how many columns (or what their names are going to be) up front.